# How can I create a dynamic priority numbering field?

Tags: list, column

The best example of what I'm trying to accomplish is in the List Settings view. When you go to list settings, it shows you all the fields with a number dropdown to determine the order you want them displayed in. The dropdown automatically limits itself to the number of fields you have and when you choose a value from that dropdown, all the other fields that used to be above that field now get pushed back.

My question is how can I create a field in my list that behaves similarly? I am creating a request list (like an IT ticketing system) and I want to be able to have a global priority field on the requests. So if a new one is added, it goes to the bottom of the list with the last number, but if it is a high-importance request, we can assign a smaller number and it will jump up the list, pushing the rest of the requests down one rank.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with some simple coding. I can think of two ways of doing this.

1. Inline editing of a ASP.net data control that displays all the list items. Using JavaScript you can change the priority on the run. Then should update all the list items when you are saving changes.
2. Create an event receiver and attach it to the list. So when an item is updated, the event receiver fires and update the all other items and give lower priority for necessary ones.

The #1 option is much interactive and #2 way ensures does not matter where you edit the list item, it gets updated. In a another word, you can combine both if you are interested as well.